# Change font size of one line UITextView?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, font-size

is it possible to change the font size of one line in a UITextView?

Thanks!

Shredder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  A `UITextView` can only contain text that is the same size, same font, and same color.

You can make more than one `UITextView`, though, and change the font size on one of them.  As long as you position them properly, it should end up looking the way you want.

Comment: Ya I thought of that I just didn't want to... Thank you thought!

Answer (score 3):

UITextView **can now have different font sizes** by using the attributedText property.

For example:

```
let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is the bigger text.", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)])
let smallText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is the smaller text", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)])
text.append(smallText) 
myTextView.attributedText = text
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at[DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) - an open source project that lets you use attributed strings. Essentially you can easily make every character in a text view a different font and size. it can take a html encoded string and turn that into an attributed string too.